# sql server partitioned view execution plan questions

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan

I have created a partitioned view for  3 tables `tb_sales2010`,`tb_sales2011`,`tb_sales2012` using check constraint 
(respectivly for each table)
datepart(year,[Date])=(2010)
datepart(year,[Date])=(2011)
datepart(year,[Date])=(2012)

schema for table 2010 (same for all other tables)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tb_Sales2010](
    [Date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL

 CONSTRAINT [PK_tb_Sales2010] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tb_Sales2010]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Date_2010] CHECK  ((datepart(year,[Date])=(2010)))
GO
```

My query is

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM partitionedTb_sales
WHERE DATEPART(YY, DATE) = 2011
```

***My question is, the execution plan indicates that it is scanning all 3 tables. Instead of looking at the check constraint and saying table b has the information it needs. Why is that. i feel the execution plan should only show 1 table being scanned.***

[image]

***Statistics turned on results***

Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'tb_Sales2012'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'tb_Sales2011'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'tb_Sales2010'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

View Definition
CREATE VIEW PartitionedTb_Sales
AS
SELECT * FROM tb_sales2010

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM tb_sales2011

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM tb_sales2012

Comment: Have you tried using an inequality instead of a function result for your partition key?  I.e. `Date BETWEEN '1/1/2011 00:00:00' AND '12/31/2011 11:59:59'`?

Comment: @jnk same result.

Comment: And is there any actual data in the tables currently?

Comment: @jnk 7 million rows split between the three tables

Comment: And is that an actual execution plan?  Bear in mind the actuals will show numbers from estimates.  I would also run the query with `SET STATISTICS IO ON` to see what's being accessed.

Comment: That is the actually execution plan

Comment: OK, run it with the IO stats to see what's being accessed.  It could be in the estimate but not used.,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8159/discussion-between-george9170-and-jnk)

Comment: Can you post the view definition too?

Answer (score 7):

The DATEPART() function still has to be performed on *every* row before any filtering can be done/calculated.

Your view would be much more efficient if you changed it like this:

```
CREATE VIEW PartitionedTb_Sales 
AS 
SELECT *, 2010 AS SalesYear FROM tb_sales2010
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2011 AS SalesYear FROM tb_sales2011
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2012 AS SalesYear FROM tb_sales2012
```

Then, instead of using DATEPART() to calculate the year for each row, it will already be defined.

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM partitionedTb_sales
WHERE SalesYear = 2011
```